# Treat C4596 as Warning

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2019, compiler-warnings

Using the compiler option `/Wall` with VS 2019 16.8.6, I'm getting a [C4596](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/c4596?view=msvc-160);

> error C4596: 'i': illegal qualified name in member declaration

for the following test program:

```
struct S {
    int S::i;
};
int main() {}
```

[Here's a godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/GTq8EY).

- The error shows up for all VS 2019 version available there with /Wall.
- [VS 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/c4596?view=msvc-150) 15.9.33 shows the same behavior.
- [VS 2015](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/c4596?view=msvc-140) doesn't show it.
- VS 2017 and 2019 even show it when all warnings are disabled with /w, however specifically disabling 4596 really disables it.

Is this a bug or am I doing/reading something wrong?`

Is there a way to treat some, especially this, error as warning (not the other way round)?

Answer (score 2):

There *is* a (somewhat weird) way to 'reset' this warning to 'normal' mode (i.e. to *not* treat it as an error); this involves using the `#pragma warning(n:xxxx)` directive, as shown below:

```cpp
#pragma warning(4:4596)
struct S {
    int S::i; // With that #pragma, this now generates 'just' a warning
};
```

> warning C4596: 'i': illegal qualified name in member declaration

Not being party to the design of the MSVC compiler, I can't really say any more about *why* this happens. However, more information on adjusting its warnings using `#pragma` directives can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/warning?view=msvc-160).

Also, possibly of interest, is that the clang-cl compiler (used from within Visual Studio) generates ***just*** a warning, with or without that pragma:

> warning : extra qualification on member 'i'
> [-Wmicrosoft-extra-qualification]

Comment: Adding that `#pragma` works on my VS-2019 (with or without "Conformance Mode" set) and also on your linked Compiler Explorer sample.